# civi api response limit working in postman but not in javascript

Tags: api, javascript

I created a postman test with api4 of civicrm. It adds to the body as x-www-form-urlencoded:

```
key: params 
value: {"limit": 5}
```

This works fine and returns only 5 results.

I tried to do the same in javascript with nodejs but the limit is always ignored.

```
const response = await axios.post(url.toString(), qs.stringify({ 
              'limit': 5,
            }), {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${mykey}`,
                Accept: '*/*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              }, });
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: How is the `{'limit': 5}` param actually getting form encoded by your code? It looks to simply be a json string?

Comment: Actually qs (querystring) should create it. However, I also tried different approaches 
e.g. 
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('params[0][limit]', '5');
or converting it manually. But nothing worked.